# Is there a way to track API calls through PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm using [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)  in my Python script and am trying to figure out a way to track the number of API calls that it has made. Is there a way to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable logging in PRAW : https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/logging.html

From that page:

> When properly configured, HTTP requests that are issued should produce
> output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Fetching: GET https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me
> Data: None
> Params: {'raw_json': 1}
> Response: 200 (876 bytes)
> ```
>
> Furthermore, any API ratelimits from POST actions that are handled
> will produce a log entry with a message similar to the following
> message:
>
> ```
> Rate limit hit, sleeping for 5.5 seconds
> ```

Simplest thing you could do is just `grep -c` over the log looking for `Fetching`. Or, of course, wire your application to more sophisticated monitoring tools.

Comment: Oh, fantastic -- and simple! Thank you very much. I feel silly for not even thinking of this.